ListColumn recomposing all items
I've created this LazyColumn with items and assigns the key with a unique identifier, each item has a unique id. But even so, when I modify the quantity of an item in the list, all items in the list are being recomposed.
I'm using the UiModel pattern to keep all screen data and I'm updating the data on the view model. I've marked the item model with @Stable annotation too.
Anyone have any idea what I'm missing here?
// ViewModel
class MainViewModel: ViewModel() {

    private val _cartUiState = MutableLiveData<CartUiState>()
    val cartUiState: LiveData<CartUiState> = _cartUiState

    init {
        _cartUiState.value = CartUiState(
            items = listOf(
                CartItem(1, "coffee", 0),
                CartItem(2, "tea", 0),
                CartItem(3, "espresso", 0)
            )
        )
    }

    fun incrementCartItemCount(itemId: Int) {
        _cartUiState.value = _cartUiState.value?.copy(
            items = _cartUiState.value?.items?.map {
                if (it.id == itemId) {
                    it.copy(quantity = it.quantity + 1)
                } else {
                    it
                }
            } ?: emptyList()
        )
    }
}

// Activity
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            val viewModel: MainViewModel = viewModel()
             val cartUiState by viewModel.cartUiState.observeAsState()

            PlaygroundTheme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    StatelessCart(
                        cartUiState = cartUiState ?: CartUiState(emptyList()),
                        onDecrement = { id -> viewModel.decrementCartItemCount(id) },
                        onIncrement = { id -> viewModel.incrementCartItemCount(id) }
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun StatelessCart(
    cartUiState: CartUiState,
    onDecrement: (id: Int) -> Unit,
    onIncrement: (id: Int) -> Unit
) {
    Column {
        LazyColumn {
            items(
                items = cartUiState.items,
                key = { item -> item.id }
            ) { item ->
                CartItem(
                    name = item.name,
                    quantity = item.quantity,
                    onDecrement = { onDecrement(item.id) },
                    onIncrement = { onIncrement(item.id) }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

// Models
@Stable
data class CartUiState(
    val items: List<CartItem>
)

@Stable
data class CartItem(
    val id: Int,
    val name: String,
    val quantity: Int
)

I'm using compose-bom:2023.08.00 (compose version 1.5.0)
You can access the project here. Branch compose-state
I've checked some articles and google documentations but I've not found a solution.

Here is your problem
StatelessCart(
    cartUiState = cartUiState ?: CartUiState(emptyList()),
    onDecrement = { id -> viewModel.decrementCartItemCount(id) },
    onIncrement = { id -> viewModel.incrementCartItemCount(id) }
)

Compose doesn't know your viewModel is stable or not, so it mark viewModel unstable
viewModel unstable -> onDecrement and onIncrement lambda mark unstable
(because it take viewmodel as one of its constructer params)
So every button got onDecrement and onIncrement as param is recomposed everytime
There is two way to fix this:
First: Annotate your ViewModelClass with @Stable
Second: Pass viewModel function as singleton lambda:
StatelessCart(
    cartUiState = cartUiState ?: CartUiState(emptyList()),
    onDecrement = viewModel::decrementCartItemCount,
    onIncrement = viewModel::incrementCartItemCount
)

Hope this help
Additional: For further improvement, List is marked as unstable, so you might want to change to ImmutableList, which is stable, from kotlinx.collections.immutable

I think you can only reach the goal with using a SnapshotStateList inside of your view model.
private val _cartUiState = mutableStateListOf<CartItem>()
val cartUiStates: List<CartItem> = _cartUiState

In the incrementCartItemCount function replace the item with the increased item.
fun incrementCartItemCount(itemId: Int) {
    val index = _cartUiState.indexOfFirst { it.id == itemId }
    _cartUiState[index] = _cartUiState[index].copy()

}

But not sure if this is a good idea because there maybe some race conditions when the list is modified on different threads.
